# Trouble understanding logic. Employees who earn more than Manager.

Tags: sql, teradata

Can you please help me understand why this query does not work for the problem below:
select a.name as 'Employee' from employee a join employee b on a.id=b.managerId and a.salary>b.salary

This solution works, but I don't understand why we should join on a.managerId=b.Id:
select a.name as 'Employee' from employee a join employee b on a.id=b.managerId and a.salary>b.salary

Can you please help me understand.

Here is the problem:
The Employee table holds all employees including their managers. Every employee has an Id, and there is also a column for the manager Id.

| Id | Name  | Salary | ManagerId |

| 1  | Joe   | 70000  | 3         |

| 2  | Henry | 80000  | 4         |

| 3  | Sam   | 60000  | NULL      |

| 4  | Max   | 90000  | NULL      |

Given the Employee table, write a SQL query that finds out employees who earn more than their managers. For the above table, Joe is the only employee who earns more than his manager.

| Employee |

| Joe      |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to understand what's happening if you use a different table alias.

```
select emp.name
from employee emp
join employee manager on emp.managerId = manager.id
where emp.salary > manager.salary
```

After the join, you'd have records that looked kind of like this if you ran select * rather than selecting a single column:

```
emp.id, emp.name, emp.salary, emp.managerid, manager.id, manager.name, manager.salary, manager.managerid
```

Once you have that, the where clause is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thank you! I got it now!